# Circles on a moving Line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

wanted to plot circles on my real time line chart. The chart generates random y value every iteration and plots it on the chart, shifting the domain. This is my code for that -

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const MARGIN = {TOP: 50, BOTTOM: 50, LEFT: 50, RIGHT: 50};
const WIDTH = svg.attr('width') - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT;
const HEIGHT = svg.attr('height') - MARGIN.TOP - MARGIN.BOTTOM;

const limit = 60;
const duration = 500;
let dataList = [];

let g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate( ${MARGIN.LEFT}, ${MARGIN.TOP} )`);

g.append('defs').append('clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'clip2')
    .append('rect')
     .attr('x', 0)
     .attr('y', 0)
     .attr('width', WIDTH)
     .attr('height', HEIGHT);

// ParseTime

const timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
     .range([0, WIDTH]);

const valueScale = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([0, 10])
     .range([HEIGHT, 0]);

const line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x((d) => timeScale(d.time))
    .y((d) => valueScale(d.value));

const xAxis =  d3.axisBottom(timeScale);

const axisCall = g.append('g')
                  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${HEIGHT})`);

axisCall.call(xAxis);

g.append('g')
 .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
 .call(d3.axisLeft(valueScale))

let pathsG = g.append('g').attr('id', 'paths').attr('class', 'paths').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip2)');

function updateChart() {
 let now = Date.now();
  dataList.push({
   time: now,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  });
  
  // Shift domain
  timeScale.domain([now - ((limit - 2) * duration), now - duration]);
  
  axisCall.transition().duration(duration).ease(d3.easeLinear, 2).call(xAxis);
  
  let minerG = pathsG.selectAll('.minerLine').data([dataList]);
  let minerGEnter = minerG.enter()
         .append('g')
         .attr('class', 'minerLine')
         .merge(minerG);
  
  let minerSVG = minerGEnter.selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
   return [d];
  });
  
  let minerSVGenter = minerSVG.enter()
                 .append('path').attr('class', 'line')
           .style('stroke', '#D073BA')
           .style('fill', 'none')
              .merge(minerSVG)
           .transition()
           .duration(duration)
           .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
           .attr('d', line(dataList))
           .attr('transform', null);
                  
   let circles = minerGEnter.selectAll('circle')/*.data(function(d) {
            return [d];
        });*/
  circles.data(dataList)
          .enter()
          .append('circle')
          .merge(circles)
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
          .attr('r', 5)
          .attr('cx', (d, i) => timeScale(d.time))
          .attr('cy', d => valueScale(d.value));

  circles.exit().remove();
  
  }

setInterval(function(){ 
   //console.log('hello');
  updateChart();
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
    <title>Real-time Line Chart D3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <svg width="960" height="500">
    </svg>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the chart is working but not the circles. Their are two problems. The chart shows the animation of circle entering the chart and the circles seem to have wrong y values. I am pretty sure the way I am appending circles is not correct. Tried taking examples from code online but nothing worked.

Any ideas how to fix the two problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circles' positions are not wrong, they are correct. They may seem wrong because you're using an interpolator (`d3.curveBasis`) for the path, which modifies it: removing the interpolator makes that clear, as in the demo below. Also, regarding the transition, the solution may be setting the circle's position in the enter selection and only transitioning the `x` position in the update selection.

Here is your code with those 2 changes only:

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const MARGIN = {
  TOP: 50,
  BOTTOM: 50,
  LEFT: 50,
  RIGHT: 50
};
const WIDTH = svg.attr('width') - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT;
const HEIGHT = svg.attr('height') - MARGIN.TOP - MARGIN.BOTTOM;

const limit = 60;
const duration = 500;
let dataList = [];

let g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate( ${MARGIN.LEFT}, ${MARGIN.TOP} )`);

g.append('defs').append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clip2')
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', WIDTH)
  .attr('height', HEIGHT);

// ParseTime

const timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, WIDTH]);

const valueScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([HEIGHT, 0]);

const line = d3.line()
  .x((d) => timeScale(d.time))
  .y((d) => valueScale(d.value));

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(timeScale);

const axisCall = g.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${HEIGHT})`);

axisCall.call(xAxis);

g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(valueScale))

let pathsG = g.append('g').attr('id', 'paths').attr('class', 'paths').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip2)');

function updateChart() {
  let now = Date.now();
  dataList.push({
    time: now,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  });

  // Shift domain
  timeScale.domain([now - ((limit - 2) * duration), now - duration]);

  axisCall.transition().duration(duration).ease(d3.easeLinear, 2).call(xAxis);

  let minerG = pathsG.selectAll('.minerLine').data([dataList]);
  let minerGEnter = minerG.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'minerLine')
    .merge(minerG);

  let minerSVG = minerGEnter.selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
    return [d];
  });

  let minerSVGenter = minerSVG.enter()
    .append('path').attr('class', 'line')
    .style('stroke', '#D073BA')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .merge(minerSVG)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
    .attr('d', line(dataList))
    .attr('transform', null);

  let circles = minerGEnter.selectAll('circle').data(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

  circles.exit().remove();

  circles = circles.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('cx', (d, i) => timeScale(d.time))
    .attr('cy', d => valueScale(d.value))
    .merge(circles);

  circles.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)
    .attr('cx', (d, i) => timeScale(d.time));

}

setInterval(function() {
  //console.log('hello');
  updateChart();
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>
<title>Real-time Line Chart D3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <svg width="960" height="500">
    </svg>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much for the clarification. Such a noob mistake.